# Getting 'java.lang.String.org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' exception

Tags: java, android, json

When I'm trying to pass an email value from EditText to php using get method by these Android code. I'm getting these error on my button click.

I have already checked my PHP code with constant variable it's fully working. So this error is from Android side.

```
EditText et;
Button b;

SharedPreferences sp;
JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
String url="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);

    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    sp= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    url=sp.getString("url", "")+"forgotpassword.php";

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String email= et.getText().toString().trim();
            if(email.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                et.setError("mail id");
            }
            else if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
                et.setError("mail format incorrect");
            }
            else {
                Log.d("url=========", url);
                try
                {

                    List<NameValuePair> det=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    det.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email.trim()));
                    JSONParser jp=new JSONParser();
                    JSONObject js=new JSONObject();
                    js=jp.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", det);
                    String result=js.getString("status");
                    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Sent ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

I need to get text that I was given in EditText to my php. That's only I needed.

Comment: Can you provide the full exception and stack trace?

Comment: It looks like this line `String result=js.getString("status");` is causing the error but not sure what the error is.

Comment: do you mean the error exception string ? it looks like this "java.lang.Nullpointer Exception Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)'on a null object reference"

Comment: i only needed to pass 'EditText' value to my php by 'GET' method and retrieve true or false response. help me please.

Comment: Please show exactly what is returned from your PHP method.

Comment: I think it should needed to return the value of status is 0 or 1. But it only showing the error i given. But when i run that php code without android. it correctly returning 0 or 1 as json string.

Comment: So it is returning just `"status": 1` or `{"status": 1}`? Trying to be sure the format coming back from your PHP method is formatted the way your Java code is expecting.

Comment: it is like `{"status":1}`